# reload application context with all springboot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I already add `@SpringBootTest` in all testcase.

'Run all test' in IDEA is OK, but when I use `Maven test` it didn't work.

how to reuse context in `Maven test` commend.

has any friend meet this problem? thx!

my test case like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
class EventControllerTest extends BaseTester{
...
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class BaseTester{}
```

maven log:

> 2018-07-04 16:09:38.766  INFO [-,,,] 12601 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@2577d6c8: startup date [Wed Jul 04 16:09:29 CST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@54eb2b70
>   2018-07-04 16:09:38.792  INFO [-,,,] 12601 --- [       Thread-9] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   Running com.fintend.ctc.controller.InviteControllerTest
>   16:09:40.535 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.fintend.ctc.controller.InviteControllerTest]
>   16:09:40.541 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
>   16:09:40.549 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
>   16:09:40.570 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test c

Comment: ps. I want to reuse context, reduce the test time

Comment: done! just delete single thread config!

Comment: Francis.Ning how did you do this config